# What does the order of the lm summary coefficients signify?

Tags: linear-regression, self-study

I have

```
fit.all <-lm(Sepal.Length ~ .,iris)
summary(fit.all)->fit.all.summary
print(fit.all.summary$coefficients)
```

[image: Output]
What are the coefficients ordered by?

Comment: Could you share the output of your last command line?

Comment: This is a generic question. I re-wrote with the iris data set to illustrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are simply in the exact order that you passed the `data.frame` to `lm()`.

```
data(iris)
iris <- iris[, c(5,4,3,2,1)] #change column order

fit.all <-lm(Sepal.Length ~ .,iris)
summary(fit.all)->fit.all.summary
print(fit.all.summary$coefficients)
```

Output:

```
                    Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)        2.1712663 0.27979415  7.760227 1.429502e-12
Speciesversicolor -0.7235620 0.24016894 -3.012721 3.059634e-03
Speciesvirginica  -1.0234978 0.33372630 -3.066878 2.584344e-03
Petal.Width       -0.3151552 0.15119575 -2.084418 3.888826e-02
Petal.Length       0.8292439 0.06852765 12.100867 1.073592e-23
Sepal.Width        0.4958889 0.08606992  5.761466 4.867516e-08
```